# Launch and pass scripted commands to a Terminal script

Tags: macos, mac, bash, terminal

I've got a.command, a script that waits for user entry (like typing something and then hitting return)  It loops forever-ish. For example, it tells the user if their entry is a leap year, or its a minecraft server. I get it going as the user like so:

```
open a.command
```

Trying to write a script that will periodically act like a user typing entries to that script.

I am having no luck with something like this:

```
i=5;
while [ $i -gt 0 ]; do
  i=$(( $i - 1 )); sleep 10; # do this once every 10 seconds for i times
  {{send text to the script a.command in the newly opened window}}
done & open a.command > a.out;
```

Doesn't have to output to a.out, I was just saving the results to that file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of doing the inter process communication inside the while loop, just print to standard out and pipe the whole loop into a.command.

So your script would look something like this:

```
i=5;
while [ $i -gt 0 ]; do
  i=$(( $i - 1 )); sleep 10; # do this once every 10 seconds for i times
  echo "Jan 1, 1970" # just echo or print your input here
done | a.command > a.out;
```

Note the use of the `|` character instead of the `&` in the last line.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work.  The a.command script opens in another terminal window, but none of the echo data shows up there.  The a.command script is a simple:

Comment: c=20;
    while [ $c -gt 0 ]; do
 c=$(( $c - 1 ));
 echo "Type the year that you want to check (4 digits), followed by [ENTER]:"
 read year
 if (( ("$year" % 400) == "0" )) || (( ("$year" % 4 == "0") && ("$year" % 100 !=
"0") )); then
  echo "$year is a leap year."
 else
  echo "This is not a leap year."
 fi
    done

Comment: Hmm, is a.command a shell script or something else? You might not need to use `open` if it's a shell script.

Comment: Its something like that script there that figures whether 4 digits is a leap year.

Comment: The eventual application of this will be to feed Save All commands to my minecraft server, which is running in a terminal window and accepts user input, just like that script.  I'll be launching it with java.

Comment: I edited my answer to remove the `open` command as it is unnecessary. However, if it's a Minecraft server you want to send commands to, this probably isn't a good solution as you'll want to be able to manually interact with the server (to gracefully shut it down at the least). For that, I'd suggest checking out this: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/107290

Comment: Well, the server I run now runs in a terminal window that I launch from a .command script that will relaunch itself after a crash or manual stop.  I'm able to interact with the window.  What I want to do is automatically interact with that window at predefined times - as if I'm typing in commands or saying something to the players.

Comment: BTW, sadly, running your new code spits out this error: a.command: command not found.

Comment: Try adding a `./` in front of a.command in my code so the last line looks like this: `done | ./a.command > a.out;` and running the code from the directory that a.command is in.

Comment: Launching the script in the terminal with open startup.command.  I now get this error:

Comment: /Users/davester/Documents/startup.command: line 5: ./a.command: No such file or directory

Comment: BTW, both startup.command and a.command have execute rights via chmod +x

Comment: Yeah, that would give a permission denied error. Hmm, try giving the absolute path to a.command.

Comment: YES!  That did it.  Thank you - I think this will work.  I'll try it on my minecraft script and let you know.  Is there a way to clean this whole thread up?